# How to wrap af:inputFile text name?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.0,
I have an inputFile component in my page that takes its text value from the name of some components. The problem is that that when the text is long it gets displayed all there and may even occupy the whole window. Is there any possibility to wrap this text value in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `<af:inputFile>` has a labelStyle [attribute:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_inputFile.html)

You can try adding the CSS in the component's inlineStyle or contentStyle

```
<af:inputFile inlineStyle="word-wrap:break-word;" />
```

It depends if the very long text is in the content or the label of the field.
If this doesn't do the trick, you can try creating a [custom skin](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/index-092146.html) and customizing the label or content style via the adf [style selectors](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/skin-selectors.html): af|inputFile::content , af|inputFile::label.

Btw, you need to check if word-wrap works on all browsers you're targeting.

Comment: Thank you for answering but you are suggesting was suggested by MohamedSanaulla in the previous answer. Changing the skin might solve this but I was requesting something simpler. However I am going to mark this as the right answer as apparently a better one is not possible :) . If I may ask, do you have experience with af:calendar component ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the labelStyle attribute of the `<af:inputFile>` component to wrap the contents of the label. I am not sure of the CSS style attribtue information for it, but searching on the net I found `word-wrap:break-word;`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, putting "word-wrap:break-word;" the label property of the <af:inputFile> does nothing, I just tried to surround the inputFile with a PannelLabelAnDMessage but nothing changed :( .Have you ever faced this issue?

Comment: I havent faced this issue. But can you try with other CSS property for enabling word wrap?

Comment: Can you give me a hint what to try? The problem in this case is that it has to be a property of the <af:inputFile> because it is its value (text value) that should be wrapped. I tried encapsulating it within other components but this does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem with af:inputFile.
Just give contentStyle="width:200px" it will solve the issue.
we can adjust the width accordingly.

Comment: Actually I want to brake the words, if the title has its words linked together ex: One_day_Jim_went_for_a_long_trip.. However thank you.